# Pattern matching on groups in list

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

I am learning Erlang using `Learn you some erlang` and I am grouping a list in tuples of 3.I do not understand why the book implementation is the following :

```
group([], Acc) ->Acc
group([A,B,X|Rest], Acc) -> group(Rest, [{A,B,X} | Acc]).
```

**Input**

```
  group([],[1,2]).
```

since it renders the following exception:

> exception error: no function clause matching
>   hth:group([],[1,2]) (d:/Erlang/AeRlang/hth.erl, line 15)

Shouldn't it be:

```
group(Acc,[X,Y,Z|T])->group([{X,Y,Z}|Acc],T);
group(Acc,_)->Acc.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it renders the following exception:
>
> exception error: no function clause matching hth:group([],[1,2])
>   (d:/Erlang/AeRlang/hth.erl, line 15)

Really?  First, let's fix the syntax error:

```
group([], Acc) ->Acc;
group([A,B,X|Rest], Acc) -> group(Rest, [{A,B,X} | Acc]).
```

In the shell:

```
~/erlang_programs$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)

1> c(a).
a.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,a}

2> a:group([], [1, 2]).
[1,2]
```

> Shouldn't it be:
>
> ```
> group(Acc,[X,Y,Z|T])->group([{X,Y,Z}|Acc],T);
> group(Acc,_)->Acc.
> ```

Let's try it:

```
11> a:group([], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]).   
[{4,5,6},{1,2,3}]
```

The first definition will throw an error when the number of elements in the list isn't divisible by 3--presumably to alert the user that something is wrong.  Your version "fails" silently.  It looks like all you did was reverse the arguments in the first version, then in the *base case* your version matches anything rather than the empty list.